# rundeck :how to correct the configuration of rundeck to access via the browser

Tags: rundeck

i have problem accessing rundeck

[2021-05-03T17:33:33,231] WARN beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'exceptionMappings' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(java.util.List)]: [public void org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(java.util.Map)]
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,756] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Starting Rundeck 3.3.10-20210301 (2021-03-02) ...
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,757] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - using rdeck.base config property: /var/lib/rundeck
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,768] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - loaded configuration: /etc/rundeck/framework.properties
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,805] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - RSS feeds disabled
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,806] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Using jaas authentication
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,811] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Preauthentication is disabled
[2021-05-03T17:33:41,918] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
[2021-05-03T17:33:42,283] WARN rundeckapp.BootStrap - [Development Mode] Usage of H2 database is recommended only for development and testing
[2021-05-03T17:33:42,590] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck startup finished in 945ms
[2021-05-03T17:33:42,877] INFO rundeckapp.Application - Started Application in 32.801 seconds (JVM running for 35.608)
Grails application running at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4440 in environment: production

Session terminated, killing shell...[2021-05-04T10:20:46,596] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck Shutdown detected
...killed.

can you help me please

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate on explaining your problem? What do you mean by "i have problem accessing rundeck"? It's a credentials issue? Or you cannot access the instance from another network location? What kind of installation are you using? (RPM/WAR?). At the end of your service.log the service seems killed, try starting it again with `systemctl start rundeckd`.

Comment: by the way I have installed a vm under redhat then I installed rundeck RPM and from my physical machine when I do http: // rundecknode_ip: 4440 it returns me on the browser error 113 no route to host and on examination of the logs I have what I have posted above when i do systemctl status rundeck it is active running

Comment: That is a VM / physical machine networking problem. Make sure that you can reach the VM services from your physical machine (check the VM firewall/selinux services). A good approach is to configure your VM network as a bridge youtube.com/watch?v=XCkKDWMYHME and access it from "outside". Another way to test Rundeck quickly is to use the Docker environment: `docker run -p 4440:4440 rundeck/rundeck:4440` and then access to the instance `http://localhost:4440`.

Comment: ca ne fonctionne pas

Comment: I mean `docker run -p 4440:4440 rundeck/rundeck:3.3.10` my bad :-)

Answer (score 0):

by the way I have installed a vm under redhat
then I installed rundeck RPM
and from my physical machine when I do http: // rundecknode_ip: 4440
it returns me on the browser error 113 no route to host and on examination of the logs I have what I have posted above
when i do systemctl status rundeck it is active running

Comment: Please add this to the original post/question :-)